# Using unset member variables within a class or struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008

It's pretty nice to catch some really obvious errors when using unset local variables or when accessing a class or struct's members directly prior to initializing them.  In visual studio 2008 you get an "uninitialized local variable used" warning at compile-time and get a run-time check failure at the point of access when debugging.

However, if you access an uninitialized struct's member variable through one of its functions, you don't get any warnings or assertions.  Obviously the easiest solution is *don't do that*, but nobody's perfect.

For example:

```
struct Test
{
    float GetMember() const { return member; }
    float member;
};
Test test;
float f1 = test.member;      // Raises warning, asserts in VS debugger at runtime
float f2 = test.GetMember(); // No problem, just keeps on going
```

This surprised me, but it makes some sense -- the compiler can't assume calling a function on an unused struct is an error, or how else would you initialize or construct it?  And anything fancier just quickly brings up so many other complications that it makes sense that it wouldn't bother classifying which functions are ok to call and when, especially just as a debugging help.  I know I can set up my own assertions or error checking within the class itself, but that can complicate some simpler structs.

Still, it would seem like within the context of the function call, wouldn't it know insides `GetMember()` that `member` wasn't initialized yet?  I'm assuming it's not only relying on static compile-time deduction, given the `Run-Time Check Failure #3` it raises during execution, so based on my current understanding of it it would seem reasonable for the same checks to apply.  Is this just a limitation of this specific compiler/debugger (Visual Studio 2008), or more tied to how C++ works?

Comment: `Is this just a limitation of this specific compiler/debugger (Visual Studio 2008), or more tied to how C++ works?` standard not forbids usage of unuinitialized variables. It's MSVC debug feature.

Comment: @ForEveR you can't use an uninitialized variable as an r-value.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore what do you means with 'can't'? Program is well-formed, but it's UB, right. But it doesn't means 'you can't'.

Comment: @ForEveR true. But you have to agree the comment does more harm than good then. I mean, saying it's OK just because it's a well-formed program but leaving out that it's UB (which is worse, because no diagnostics is required)...

Comment: @ForEveR I mean... can you divide by zero, just because the program is well-formed?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore no. agree. but in my comment i don't tell, that usage of unitialized variable is OK.

Comment: @ForEveR I know what you mean, I'm just saying the wording can be better. Saying it's not forbidden kinda implies that it's OK. At least to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably notice that the warning is about `test` not being initialized. Which is why the warning & run-time failure only applies to the line

```
float f1 = test.member;
```

This leads to undefined behavior, and, at least in debug mode, MSVS does some checking and is able to crash (in release, the bug would probably be hidden and you'd just end up with a bogus value in `f1`).

The next line however doesn't directly result in UB. `f1` isn't read, nor are any of its data members (directly). A method is called, and the compiler can't know that the member function would yield UB on an un-initialized object. The function could just print something to the screen and not read any of the members, which would be OK. Well, the compiler **could** theoretically know because it sees the code, but it doesn't dig that deep. A static code analyzer *might* alert you on the problem.

Comment: @DougKavendek if you look in the disassembly, you'll see that the check is inserted *because* the compiler sees the uninitialized variable. It'd just get complicated (or really slow, even in debug mode) after that trivial case.

Comment: Aha, I guess I was thinking it was doing a dynamic check at runtime with some kind of sentinel uninitialized starting value, but I hadn't even thought to look at the disassembly.  I think I see what's going on now.  Good to replace my assumptions with facts!